# how to achieve the same animation for finish() and onBackPressed?

Tags: android, android-intent, onbackpressed, activity-finish

As default `onBackPressed()` has its animation and `finish()` has its own. how to has the same animation (onBackPressed) when we call to `finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

The default `onBackPressed()` behavior calls through to [`finishAfterTransition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#finishAfterTransition()), so you should call that same method if you want the same animation.

Comment: After to `startActivity()`? if so the transition remains the same.

Comment: What does `startActivity()` have to do with `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: I'm overwriting `onBackPressed()` with the purpose of  start an activity and clear back stack but the transaction is different compared  when we just touch on "back button" and don't overwriting the `onBackPressed()`.